# Basic C operations

Tags: c

I have this task that I'm stumbling upon. I'll first go ahead with the description and requirements for it and then point out what I'm having trouble coping with.

> *Build a block scheme and a program that reads another C-based program and finds:*

- Number of lines in the program
- Number of conditional operators if and if/else

  The program needs to start with a menu disposing with the following options:

  > - Reading the program from a file and storing the result in a separate file (the user has to input the names of both files whilst the program
  >     file has to end in “.C”)
  > - Reading the program from a file and outputting the result on the screen (the user selected file has to end in “.C”).
  > - Reading of the program from the keyboard and inserting a file selected by the user;
  > - Reading of the program from the keyboard and outputting on the screen; The program has to be written in different functions for each
  >     operation.

  Reading of the file has to be done line by line.

First question is what is a block scheme and what '*reading from a keyboard*' refers to?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: The block scheme does refer to a flow chart?

Comment: Reading from a keyboard is the operation of storing key strokes to do something useful with it in the program. For instance, taking the filename to read as input from the keyboard.

Comment: I presume this is a homework/class project assignment? We can give you some hints, but we're not going to do the whole thing for you. I would think that your instructor would have told you what they expect for a "block scheme". From the sound of it, you need to analyze the C program input from a file (or from the keyboard) and determine its block structure (nesting, etc.). Reading from a keyboard would simply be typing in the _data_ at the keyboard (standard input).

Comment: "Reading from a keyboard" = as contrasted with "reading from a file". Not really written with clarity in mind, as you might want to point out to your teacher.

Comment: I think "Reading from a keyboard" means exactly that, meaning the user types in the entire input program.

Comment: I did not ask for the task to be written for me, nor do I expect someone to. I just needed a bit of clarification as to what the professor meant with the above mentioned and I already got my answers. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't understand any of the words of the assignment, then you need to go talk to the person who set you the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block scheme is another, albeit less used, term for a [block diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram), or a flow chart.

A block diagram is:

> a diagram of a system in which the principal parts or functions are represented by blocks connected by lines that show the relationships of the blocks.

Or in other words, it's a way of using pen and paper to construct what will be the flow of your program prior to writing any code. Typically they used a set of shapes to mean certian things, circles/ovals can show states/starts/ends, a rectangle may repersent a function, a diamond could be used for a decision point, etc.

As you'er asking about a specific homework problem it is best to clairify what your instructor expects, but a quick example of a block scheme for a progrm could be something like:

[image]

This maybe too algorithimic for what your instcutor wants, they may just want to see blocks only stating `"get input from user"`, `"open a file"` showing the flow at a moduler level and ignorning the decision details as in checking error conditions.

Now as far as `"•Reading of the program from the keyboard"`, as I didn't write the assignment, it's again speculation, but I'm pretty sure your instructor is simply saying get input via `stdin`. The mechanism would be dependent on what you're learning in class, but in C, just something like [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) or [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) or whatever you know can get the input from the keyboard.